# EWS- Service XmlDeserializatin Exception was unhandles

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, exchangewebservices

Problem is reading email in Exchange web Service. I am using c# winform(2012)

Error: Service XmlDeserializatin Exception was unhandles
The expected XML node type was XmlDeclaration, but the actual type is Element.

```
ExchangeService service=new ExchangeService (ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
        service.Credentials=new WebCredentials ("xxx@outlook.com","Password","outlook.com");
        service.AutodiscoverUrl("xxxx@outlook.com",RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
        service.TraceEnabled = true;
        service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
        FindItemsResults<Item> findResults=service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,new ItemView(10));

        foreach (Item  item in findResults.Items)
{
    item.Load();
     txtRequest.Text +=item.Subject.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Suresh, can you please capture a trace and post the request and response here? How to trace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn495632(v=exchg.150).aspx. Also, what version of the EWS Managed API are you using?

Comment: Jason, I Used Exchange2010, i trying to login to my Outlook AC. But  Account is blocked. Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to connect to an outlook.com mailbox? You can't use EWS to connect to outlook.com.